# SSIS Delete records using one table that exists in a different table from different databases (SSDT)

Tags: mysql, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using a data flow task and 2 Ole Db sources. The 2 sources bring in data from tables on 2 different databases on the same server. The 2 tables can be mapped by ids. All of the ids from the second table (closedstops) exist in the first table (stops). I need to remove all the the closed stops by id from the first table. Afterwards I need to export the first table out of the database into a text file.

Do I need to use a merge join before deleting or do I need to use a ole db command to delete records (see attached screenshot). I have looked at many questions and answers on stackoverflow as well as tutorials and none of them quite answer my question. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Screenshot Example SSDT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed stops is the driver table. Leave it be.

Instead of an OLE DB Source table for "stops" change that to a Lookup Component. You are only interested in rows that match.

And then you can use your OLE DB Command to fire off single delete statements.

My preference for performance and traceability would be to insert all the "to be deleted" ids into a table on the Stops database. When the Data Flow has completed, an Execute SQL Task would then fire up to perform the deletes in a set based operation(s).

Comment: Thanks. I managed to add the lookup table and add the deleted ids into a table on the stops database. As far as the Execute SQL Task, I attached it after the data flow. I used the server that has both the stops table and delete ids table. In the sql statement of the execute task I have delete dbo.stops from dbo.stops a 
inner join dbo.delete_stops b on a.stop_id = b.stop_id . Can execute sql tasks perform deletes in this way? It isn't deleting.

Comment: If it's not deleting, then it's not finding a match (or it's raising an error somewhere in the process). What is the state of dbo.delete_stops? Are there any records in it? If there is at least one record, does it have a match in dbo.stops i.e. `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.stops AS S WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.delete_stops AS D WHERE D.stop_id = S.stop_id)`